# Convert kABemailProperty to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, addressbookui

In my address book app, when I fetch email id for the contact, I et something like this:

```
ABMultiValueRef 0x2994e0 with 1 value(s)
0: null (0x3f5655e0) - xyz@gmail.com (0x2994b0)
```

How to get string value i.e. only

```
 xyz@gmail.com
```

from above result?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code. ABMultiValueRef ... looks like an array which you are converting to NSString maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This is what you have currently (i.e. the multivalues)
ABMultiValueRef emailValues = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

// This is how you extract the first item from the multivalues:
CFStringRef cfEmailAddress = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailValues, 0);

// This is how you convert it to an NSString.
NSString *emailAddress = CFBridgingRelease(cfEmailAddress);
```